# Last-child pseudo class for list not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

The last-child pseudo class I am using on a list is not working. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvLk/

HTML:

```
<ul class="categories">
    Categories
    <li>{category_name}</li>
    <li>{category_name}</li>
    <li>{category_name}</li>
    <li>{category_name}</li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.categories {
   text-align: center;
}

ul.categories li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #E6E6E6;
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
}

ul.categories li:first-child{
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
}

ul.categories li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 32px 32px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 32px 32px;
}
```

I have Googled it and seen some posts on StackOverflow asking about cross-browser issues.
I am not asking about cross-browser issues, I am using Chrome v23, last-child should work.

What am I overlooking/doing wrong?

Comment: The JSFiddle link is borked / nonexistent.

Comment: You jsfiddle link is dead. post your code or correct the links

Comment: Your code work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/qNh75/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple typo: You wrote `<ul>` instead of `</ul>`, so the last `<li>` was not really the last child.

Corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvLk/1/

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks so much. It's been bugging me for close to an hour, and I just couldn't find it. 

I was pretty certain it was correct but wow, code blindness...thanks again! (:

Comment: Yeah, it took me quite some time to see that. It's difficult to notice something like that... I even validated the CSS, just to be sure everything is OK, but didn't think to validate the HTML as well.